# Intersection of two unions

Tags: probability

More specifically what is

$$p((A\cup B) \cap (B\cup B^{c}))$$ where $B^{c}$ is the complement of $B$.

Do we take the intersection of each set separately, ie.

$$p((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^{c}) \cup (B \cap B) \cup (B \cap B^{c}))$$

$$p(A\cap B) + p(A\cap B^{c}) + p(B \cap B) + p(B \cap B^{c})$$

Leaving

$$p(A\cap B) + p(A\cap B^{c}) + p(B)$$

Is this correct?

Comment: The union of a set and its complement is the whole space; the intersection of a set with the whole space is the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is not correct. In general, you only have $p(A\cup B) = p(A) + p(B)$ if you know that $A$ and $B$ do not intersect, that is, $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Since $B\cup B^c$ is the whole universe, you have $(A\cup B)\cap (B\cup B^c)=A\cup B$.